# How to do pagination inside php file which is passed by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I am trying to do pagination in my php file fetch_data.php which is called from a ajax function in index.php but it is not showing the required result
Here is my code from fetch_data.php

```
<?php

require 'dbserver.inc.php';
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM detail WHERE status = '1'
 ";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 $number = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $results_per_page = 1;

 $number_of_pages = ceil($number/$results_per_page);
 if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
     $page = 1;
     echo"1";
   } else {
      echo"2";
     $page = $_GET['page'];
   }
  $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;
 if(isset($_POST["action"]))
 {

  $query = "
   SELECT * FROM detail WHERE status = '1'
  AND LIMIT" . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page ;

  if(isset($_POST["jobtype"]))
  {
     $jobtype_filter = implode("','", $_POST["jobtype"]);
     $query .= "
     AND  Job IN('".$jobtype_filter."')";
  }
  if(isset($_POST["salary"]))
  {
     $salary_filter = implode("','", $_POST["salary"]);
     $query .= "
     AND  Salary IN('".$salary_filter."')";
  }
  if(isset($_POST["category"]))
  {
     if($_POST["category"] == 'Choose Category')  
     {  
          $query .= "";  
     } 
     else
     {
     $category =  $_POST["category"];
     $query .= "
     AND  JobCat like('".$category."')";
  }}
  if(isset($_POST["location"]))
  {
     if($_POST["location"] == 'Choose Location')  
     {  
          $query .= "";  
     } 
     else
     {
     $location =  $_POST["location"];
     $query .= "
     AND  City like('".$location."')";
  }}
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo'

        <!-- Single Employers List -->
         <div class="candidate-list-layout" >
             <div class="cll-wrap">
                 <div class="cll-thumb">
                    <a href="company-detail.html">';?>
              <img class="img_responsive" alt="" src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Logo']); ?>" /> <?php echo'</a> 
                </div>
               <div class="cll-caption">
                     <h4><a href="company-detail.html">'.$row['Name'].'</a><span><i class="ti-briefcase"></i>'.$row['Title'].'</span></h4>
                     <ul>
                         <li><i class="ti-location-pin cl-danger"></i>'.$row['City'].' fetch ,'.$row['Country'].'</li>
                         <li><i class="ti-medall cl-success"></i>Established: 1984</li>
                     </ul>
                 </div>
             </div>


        ';}


        echo'<div class="row mrg-0">
        <ul class="pagination">';
        for($page = 1 ; $page<=$number_of_pages;$page++){
        echo'
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php?page='.$page.'">'.$page.'</a></li>
       ';}
       echo'     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></li> 
       </ul>
   </div>';
   }
?>
```

i want to  filter the data a also due to which i have to include these other lines of codes and it is also not redirercting to other page except the one it is currently in and when included these filter code it is showing boolean error on mysqli_query too.